# Bootstraps responsive-utilities.less as single Less file?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, less

I want to use the visible / hide system from bootstrap without including the full framework... I try to include just the responsive-utilities.less but then i get errors from lessphp...

Anyone know maybe a site where i can get this visible system seperate as stand alone less file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import the variables and mixins as well:

```
@import "less/variables";
@import "less/mixins";
@import "less/responsive-utilities";
```

You should also wonder if lessphp can compile the latest version of Bootstrap in the first place. See issues like https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/598

Finally Bootstrap requires the autoprefix postprocessor. When compiling your Les code with PHP you can not run this postprocessor (without installing Node first).

Comment: Tanks for this informations. So exist maybe a light version of this show/hide file without this complex autoprefix postprocessor?